# Lowering two expressions in an equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, mactex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfrac, array, tabu, multirow, graphicx, setspace, dcolumn, tikz}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
%the argument for d specifies the maximum number of decimal places
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\text{Z}&= \sum\frac{{(\text{y}_\text{i}_\text{z}-\bar{\text{y}}})}{\text{s}_\text{y}\_text{i}}\\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want to lower two expressions, in this case y (lower i) and even lower z. Thanks in advance for some help

Comment: Why those `\text{...}` there are no reason for them. And please post something that compiles. There are double subscript.

Comment: Not recommended, but you could try `{y_i}_{z}`.  Double subscripts are flagged bad for a reason.

Comment: The only subscript that does make some sense is `y_{i_z}`. @StevenB.Segletes 'solution' is valid as well, though I would suggest to parenthesize more. Like in `y_{(i_z)}` or `{(y_i)}_z`. A better way of two subscripts is to seperate them with a comma.

Comment: presumably your full document has several equations grouped together.  otherwise, there's no reason to use `align`, and some good reasons not to (mentioned in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82171/579)).

Answer (score 1):

While emphasizing that double subscipts are not a good practice, if your notation demanded it, you could customize the drop of the subscripts with the `stackengine` package, to a form you found least visually offensive.  I create the macro `\doublesub`, whose baseline drop is controlled by a settable stackgap (shown as 1pt, 2pt, and 3pt in the below example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{2pt}
\def\stacktype{L}
\newcommand\doublesub[2]{%
  \stackunder{}{$\scriptstyle #1$\stackunder{}{$\scriptstyle #2$}}}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{1pt}
\[
Z = \sum \frac{y\doublesub{i}{z}-\bar{y}}{s\doublesub{y}{i}}
\]
\setstackgap{L}{2pt}
\[
Z = \sum \frac{y\doublesub{i}{z}-\bar{y}}{s\doublesub{y}{i}}
\]
\setstackgap{L}{3pt}
\[
Z = \sum \frac{y\doublesub{i}{z}-\bar{y}}{s\doublesub{y}{i}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should also consider alternatives to the double subscript, for example, adopting the notation `y_{i(z)}` where the term in parenthesis would be what had been the second "subscript".

Comment: For some reason this \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{2pt}
\def\stacktype{L}
\newcommand\doublesub[2]{%
  \stackunder{}{$\scriptstyle #1$\stackunder{}{$\scriptstyle #2$}}}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{1pt}
\[
Z = \sum \frac{y\doublesub{i}{z}-\bar{y}}{s\doublesub{y}{i}}
\]
\setstackgap{L}{2pt}
\[
Z = \sum \frac{y\doublesub{i}{z}-\bar{y}}{s\doublesub{y}{i}}
\]
\setstackgap{L}{3pt}
\[
Z = \sum \frac{y\doublesub{i}{z}-\bar{y}}{s\doublesub{y}{i}}
\]
\end{document} wont work for me, i get "LaTeX Error: File 'stackengine.sty' not found.

Comment: @user34537 Most LaTeX installations will download new packages they need.  Yours apparently does not.  The package can be found at http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine.  If you download the .sty file to your current directory, it should compile.  In the long term though, you need to find the directory where LaTeX stores your local installation, and put the sty file there.  Downloading and reading the PDF will show you how the package can be utilized.